# menu css3 style in css and IE

Tags: css

I have a question ,  i need something like this

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#1e3c84), to(#2a5bd0)) #1CA6D6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #021748;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
margin-right: 5px;
```

But in CSS2 ? to show in IE correctly and other browsers

How i can do that? what is the  properties or  i can do with image? how? or something similar
very thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

All modern browsers support rounded corners and gradient. The older versions of ie can support these features using scripts like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: thanks sotiris , but doesn't work look http://goo.gl/Qa5zh , I add the   behavior: url(PIE.htc);

Comment: @FelipeIgnacioVictorianoVict keep in mind that the path to pie.htc must be relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.

Comment: thanks @sotiris, I use behavior: url(/wp-content/themes/sw/images/PIE.php); but doesn't  work too :( , Can i can do wrong?

Comment: @FelipeIgnacioVictorianoVict I don't know much of wordpress. Read http://www.position-relative.com/2011/01/using-css3-pie-in-wordpress-custom-themes/ may help you

Answer (score 1):

Border radius doesn't work in older browsers... you will have to draw the corners yourself, slice them and then build the div or button yourself :)

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

http://www.search-this.com/2007/02/12/css-liquid-round-corners/

**Update**

Or use @Sotiris link :)